# JavaFX - Replace standard CheckBox with image

Tags: css, checkbox, javafx-2

What I wanted to do is replace the standard JavaFX checkBox with my own pictures.
I made many searches and I found :

- *-fx-graphic : url*
- *-fx-background-image : url*

But, in both cases, neither does what I want.

Comment: you cant just change the image. you will need to create your own control, with an own renderer

Comment: Thanks, but, Is there a way to do that with css ?

Comment: Sry css can only change design, but the checkbox is not a pickture it is a rendered control without pictures

Comment: Ok, thanks, gonna take a look to the rendered option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a tutorial, please, consult [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm). There was a lot of [new stuff](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm) that was added in 2.2. Also, the [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) covers pretty much everything you need to know about FXML. Finally, Hendrik Ebbers made an extremely helpful [blog post](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/) about custom UI controls.

Comment: The "Mastering JavaFX 8 Controls" (http://www.guigarage.com/javafx-book/) book will contain a chapter about skinning with CSS and a chapter about custom controls.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the CSS I used to replace the checkbox with my own images.  This is based off the JavaFX8 Modena stylesheet, but should be fairly close for Caspian.  Replace the urls with the location of your images relative to your CSS sheet.

```
.check-box>.box {
  -fx-background-insets: 0;
  -fx-background-radius: 0;
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.check-box>.box>.mark {
  -fx-background-image: url("unmarked.png");
  -fx-background-position: center;
  -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
  -fx-shape: none;
}

.check-box:selected>.box>.mark{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-background-image: url("marked.png");
}
```